# Creating New Public Class

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a new class for my Items.csv file. When compiling, the code gives me an error message:

> Illegal static declaration in inner class MainActivity.TreasureHunt
> modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Here's my code example:

```
public class TreasureHunt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "C:\\.android\\Treasure\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\items.csv";
        String line = ",";

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
}
```

How can I change up the main function in order to get this to work?

Comment: The code here seems to be fine. Where are you exactly getting the problem?

Comment: It sounds like a.) you're putting this code **inside** an existing code, instead you should have create a new Java file called `TreasureHunt.java`. and b.) you're doing this in an Android project: `public static void main` and fixed code paths starting with `C:\\` don't make any sense in Java: decide if you're doing Android development **or** normal desktop Java development, don't mix them.

Comment: The error message points to the main portion before the (String[] args) {. I hoonestly have no idea what is causing  the error to populate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that `TreasureHunt` is being defined inside of another class (`MainActivity`) - so it is an inner class and static methods are not allowed up to Java version 15, restriction relaxed in Java 16 <sup>**1**</sup>.

Solutions:

- move the class out of `MainActivity`; or
- make it `static` <sup>**2**</sup>; or
- use a newer Java version (e.g. Java 16)

Java Language Spcification (JLS-8.1.3):

- up to Version 15: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-130)

  > **It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable**
- Version 16: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-130)

  > All of the rules that apply to nested classes apply to inner classes. In particular, an inner class may declare and inherit static members (§8.2), and declare static initializers (§8.7), even though the inner class itself is not `static`.

---

**1** [JEP 395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) introduction of `records`

**2** I would not recommend making it `static` just to avoid the error message. It should match the model, the idea, the *design* being implemented. I believe that having a `public` inner/nested class is an indication that the design is not perfect.

Comment: Changing it to static fixed the issue. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like *TreasureHunt* is an inner class. As of java specification

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.

And inner classes cannot have static members unless it is final.

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        static final int x = 3;  // OK: constant variable
        static int y = 4;  // Compile-time error: an inner class
    }
    static class NestedButNotInner{
        static int z = 5;    // OK: not an inner class
    }
    interface NeverInner {}  // Interfaces are never inner
}
```

So you can *TreasureHunt* a nested class but not an inner class by making it static.

```
public static class TreasureHunt {
    ...
```

For more information please refer [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)